# Firefox display bug - :before selector?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am working on this [website](http://stives-holiday.com) and it appears fine on Chrome and IE.

**The problem is that 'postcard' does is not positioned correctly in Firefox.**

I am trying to achieve a postcard effect by using the before selectors to add one half image and one half white background to my #postcard div.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="postcard" class="grid">
    <div id="featured-content" class="grid col-300 text">
        <h1 class="featured-title">
            Footsteps Cottages
        </h1>
        <h2 class="featured-subtitle">
            Home From Home Holiday Cottages
        </h2>

    </div>

    <div id="postcardback" class="grid col-300 fit">
    <div class="stamps">
        <a href="/st-ives"><img class="size-medium wp-image-19" alt="stamp" src="/stamp2.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
    </div> <!--end of .stamps-->

<div class="postcard-lines">
    <div class="postcard-line">
        Three luxury, self-catering
    </div>
    <div class="postcard-line">
        holiday cottages - Flip Flops,
    </div>
    <div class="postcard-line">
        Sandals & Barefoot. Each 
    </div>
    <div class="postcard-line">
        just a walk away from the
    </div>
    <div class="postcard-line">
        stunning seaside in Downalong
    </div>
    <div class="final-postcard-line">
        <img class="size-medium wp-image-19" alt="_IK1_2595" src="/footsteps-kisses.png" width="280" height="100">
    </div>

</div><!--end of postcard-lines-->
```

**CSS**:

```
    #postcard {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 57.446808510638%;
    display: table;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#postcard:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -2;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
}

#featured-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

#featured-content:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(/IK1_25931.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}
```

I am new to HTML and CSS (as you may have guessed), could someone help me fix this so that it displays correctly in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add below `left:0` on your ID `#postcard:before` pseudo class.

```
#postcard:before {
left: 0; /*Add this line*/
}
```

Check the Firefox screenshot with and without `left` property.

USING `left:0`[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify your css as like this

```
#postcard:before {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-size: cover;
    bottom: 0;   // ---------------- Add this line
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;  // *************** Remove this line
    height: 100%;   // ************************ Remove this line
    left: 0;  // ---------------- Add this line
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;  // ---------------- Add this line
    top: 0;   //------------------ Add this line
    width: 100%;   // **************************  Remove this line
    z-index: -1;   // -----------  Add this line
}
```